# Android: open failed: ENOENT No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I know have many question like my question. But It is different. I copy file from folder A to folder B in `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` use mothod below:

```
    public static String copyFile(String path) {
        String fileToName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        File pathFrom = new File(path);
        File pathTo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.noname");
        File file = new File(pathTo, fileToName + ".bak");

        while (file.exists()) {
            fileToName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            file = new File(pathTo, fileToName + ".bak");
        }

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(pathFrom);
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(data);
            out.write(data);
            in.close();
            out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }
```

The path param is: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/image_preview.jpg".
When execute this method I got an error: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/tree_leaves_sunlight.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.
Folder `.noname` have exists.
Is there any suggestion for my problem?

**UPDATE: This file I opening with `ImageView`. When I not open I can copy. But When I opening I got this error.
PS: I preview the image in`ImageView`. And there have a `Button` copy image. When click to Button execute method copy this image to other folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the File object for the parent directory
 `File pathTo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.noname")`
Don't forget to actually create this folder

```
 pathTo.mkdirs();
```

Also try to open file you're trying to copy in the gallery. It can be damaged and Android just can't open it.

Comment: please see my update. This method work fine when not open file. But In there I opening this file with `ImageView`.

Comment: what do you mean by opening with ImageView? you've set this file as background?

Comment: Oh!. I preview the image in `ImageView`. And there have a `Button` copy image. When click to `Button` execute method copy this image to other folder.